# mysql time comparison returning zero records

Tags: mysql, date-comparison

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `appointment` WHERE 
`appointment_full_date_from` = '2014-09-20 22:30:00'
```

And the table appointment with an appointment

[image]

The type of the `appointment_full_date_from` and `appointment_full_date_to` is `datetime`.

When I run the above query it must return the visible record from the table. But it is not doing so and returning 0 rows.

I also tried the following query but no luck.

```
SELECT * FROM `appointment` WHERE 
`appointment_full_date_from` = STR_TO_DATE('2014-09-20 22:30:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
```

What is wrong here? Can anybody help me?

Comment: I can't reproduce this, see [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ac845/1).

Comment: This is a challenge for programmers all over the World. And shame on mysql owners

Comment: I don't get your meaning. How can you reproduce this problem? Maybe it's a display trick with fractional seconds, see [updated fiddle](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). What result does `SELECT * FROM appointment` produce?